# How can I make a php session to never expire (in the conf file, no code)

Tags: php, session

I would like to manage the time that a session expire to be forever.

What do I have to change In the php configuration file so this change is permanent and I don't have to implement this in all the code I write?

After I make a change in the php file, do I need to restart apache for the changes to take effect?

Comment: You could set your own database handlers and save the sessions in a db or adjust your php ini settings

Comment: @Nitin Yes, I want to change my php settings to be able to not expire the sessions. Do you know where I have to do that? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible to store the session infinitely unless you do not use garbage collection in php. You could try to set the php ini settings and set the time to 10 years

```
// set the max life time, after this, session is seen as garbage
session.gc_maxlifetime=315360000
```

If you have cookies enabled:

```
session.use_cookies=1
#session.use_only_cookies=1

// set the cookie expiration as well
session.cookie_lifetime=315360000
```

To avoid Int overflow, do not use a value larger than 2,147,483,647 as this is the max an Int32 can hold.

Comment: The link you provided is for code not for config file and I have session.gc_maxlifetime  currently set to 0. What do I need to set it to?

Comment: Thank you again for this answer. I was just curious, why do I need to set gc_probability to 100? If I understand well that setting is for garbage collection.

Comment: My mistake. Updated my answer. Garbage collection removes inactive sessions, should be set to 1 or lower. If you have not used a session then it might get removed if garbage collection kicks in at session init

Comment: so what do I need to set those variables to?

Comment: If I understand right, the session will still be alive even after the browser gets closed, correct? What if I want to session to be active until the browser gets closed?

Comment: Set the cookie lifetime to 0. This will expire the cookie after the browser is closed and a new session will be created if cookie based session is active. Session use only cookies set to 1.

Comment: Thank you @Nitin, I'm implementing your answer. so I was just curious about this variable: session.gc_probability do I need to set it to 0 or 1?

Comment: Set to 1, if you switch it off, session files will not be deleted which will cause performance issues, unless you delete them yourself.

Comment: what if i don't set `session.use_cookies=1` ?